# Can I use ss and filter on PID and FD?

Tags: socket, ss

I'd like to be able to run `ss` and filter on `PID=$(pgrep emacs)` and `FDs=(5u|6u|8u)`. Does `ss` support filtering on either (or both) of these? Or is the best option to compose with `grep`?

I'm currently using `lsof`, but I'd prefer to use `ss`:

```bsh
lsof -p $(pgrep emacs) | rg '\b(5|6|8)u\b'
```

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
ss -tlnp | grep -w emacs | grep -E 'fd=(5|6|8)\)'
```

work for you?